# ¿ Por qué Eclipse no me genera el método toString?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9

cuando voy a generar automáticamente  el método toString me salta este error:

```
Cannot create method implementations.

Reason: C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.4\lib\jrt-fs.jar\java.base[java.base is not on its project's build path
```

Gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse tiene un [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521995) para el soporte de Java 9 en la versión actual. El ingeniero a cargo de arreglarlo ha marcado la versión objetivo en 4.8 M6.

Si quieres seguir usando Java 9, vas a tener que esperar a que salga esa versión. Si no es necesario, te sugiero cambiar a Java 8.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo he solucionado, he desinstalado java 9.